# "Recycling" question

Tags: feature-request, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

I have asked a question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821810/any-example-of-dashboard-widget-in-ajax-or-html-5-with-users-interactivity

There is only one view which could mean nobody even saw it.

Aren't there any mechanism that could "recycle" the question to give it a chance to be seen ?

Answer (score 2):

Unanswered posts will be brought back to the main page by the Community user as determined by a certain algorithm. You can also make a meaningful edit which will bump the question.